# Generate a random number from a specific number?

Tags: java, random

I want to generate a random number from a specific number.
For example:

If I have this number 1234, I want to generate a random number from it (or for it) to replace the old number. But that new number is only for the old number.

The purpose is, receiving a number, change it to a random number, but knowing that that random number belongs to the old number.

This is what I have so far:

```
long seed ="seed".hashCode();
Random rnd = new Random(seed);
int a = fourDigitIntRandom(rnd);
int b = fourDigitIntRandom(rnd);

public static int fourDigitIntRandom(Random rnd){
    int a1 = rnd.nextInt(10);
    int a2 = rnd.nextInt(10);
    int a3 = rnd.nextInt(10);
    int a4 = rnd.nextInt(10);
    int a = Integer.parseInt(a1+""+a2+""+a3+""+a4);
    return a;
}
```

However, this is only to generate a 4-digit random number.

**BETTER EXAMPLE**

I have several files. In each file there are several number corresponding to phone numbers.

I want to anonymize each number by changing the last 4 digit of that number, to a new number generated randomly given the name of the file as it seed.

but i want that the changes for each number, be always the same for that number.

so if i have the number 12345678 and change it to 12349876 (9876 is a random number).

and then later in the file, the same number appears, i want the change to be the same.

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for encryption or hashing, not random numbers.

Comment: Your question makes no sense. How can a random number belong to an old number? That beats the randomness purpose.

Comment: And btw, a hash is NOT bijective (you can't get the original value that was hashed).

Comment: @m0skit0 True, I still couldn't tell whether this would be encryption or hashing.

Comment: I think I understand what OP is trying to say here but I suspect we have a case of the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) here.

Comment: a) Do you want the same source number to produce the same random number each time? b) Given the random number, do you want it to be easy to discover the original number given a pass key? b) Given the random number, do you want it to be easy to discover the original number?

Comment: maybe just creating a "real" random number, and storing the new random number and the old number in a map for later lookup?

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon a) yes b) given the name of the file as a seed. See the new example i gave :)

Comment: So we're looking at a straightforward encryption, probably a symmetric-key one.

Comment: This is called "hashing". Google it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is how i solve my problem:
first i created a static ArrayList of String containing all the numbers with 4 digits:

```
private static ArrayList<String> getListOfValues(){
    ArrayList<String> listInt = new ArrayList<String>(10000);
    for(int i = 0; i < 10000; i++){
        if(i < 10) listInt.add("000"+i);
        else if(i < 100) listInt.add("00"+i);
        else if(i < 1000) listInt.add("0"+i);
        else listInt.add(Integer.toString(i));
    }
    return listInt;
}
```

then using the method shuffle from Collections, i would randomize the ArrayList based on a seed (from the file's name)

```
ArrayList<String> listOfAnonValues = getListOfValues();
Collections.shuffle(listOfAnonValues,new Random(filename.hashCode()));
```

and then, whenever i would want to anonymize a number, i would use that number as the index of the ArrayList to get the number to replace.
and so, every number of 4 digits would have a unique random number to replace it, based on the filename

Sorry for all the confusion and thanks for all the help you guys gave, which helped a lot ;)

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:
`

```
public static String nDigitIntRandom(Random rnd, int numOfdigits) {
final StringBuilder sb  = new StringBuilder();
for(int i = 0; i < numOfdigits; i++) {
    sb.append(rnd.nextInt(10));
}
return sb.toString();
}
```

`
You are probably better off using Strings rather then ints as you can exceed MAX_INT easilly. You will also need to keep the seed used for every phone number